# How do you call an ASMX OR WCF Service?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I am trying to learn how to call a SOAP based service from a WSDL.  I can't seem to find any element solutions online, and so at the risk of loosing reputation, I want to ask if you can help me out.  I know that people MUST be able to do it a lot.  I want a simple straight forward example, nothing crazy.

I have searched high and low in google, and everything that I see is highly complex.  I understand that I will have to do some more manual work than I would have to do in .NET, and in a way its sad, but I fully understand.

I am not asking you to do this for me, but I am asking for examples that you have used in the past.  Please do not mark this as a duplicate question, because I have also searched StackExchange for this also.

Comment: Unfortunately, your search "ASMX/WCF from Swift" is a really specific topic trying to cover two unrelated technologies, so it's no surprise that anything you'll find will be "highly complex". Try to research on "soap requests from iOS", then work your way from porting the solutions you find to WCF and swift.

Comment: I have searched for both separately.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very different to other http requests.

You have to set up a request with the WCF endpoint:

```
// Service URL
let serviceUrl = URL(string: "http://your.request.url")
// Service request using the serviceURL
var serviceRequest = URLRequest(url: serviceUrl!)
```

Set the headers fields: **Content-Type** and **SOAPAction**.  Also set the request verb (**POST**, **GET**, etc.)

Last set the request body with the **SOAP envelope** encoded as `Data`.

You cann use a URLSession dataTask to invoke.

I answered some time ago a question that might help you, follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41274631/swift-3-wcf-service/45246863#45246863)

Comment: Please include context with your answer, rather than just linking. Or mark as duplicate if the question is answered by your other SO answer.

Answer (score -1):

I use [SOAPEngine](https://github.com/priore/SOAPEngine) allows you to access web services using a iOS app and Mac OS X app.